# Text is not clearning onClick (creating dynamic textarea)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to clear the text when the user onclick on the text input control as shown below but its not happening... below is the code

```
 var generate_message = $("<textarea onclick='if (this.value == 'Enter message here...') this.value = '''  rows='5' cols='45' id='comment'>Enter message here...</textarea>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use single quote in html and javascript. It causes confusion in browser renderer

Usually, I separate the use of single quote and double quote. I use double quote for html and single quote for javascript

See example below

```
<textarea onclick="if (this.value == 'Enter message here...') this.value = ''"  rows="5" cols="45" id="comment">Enter message here...</textarea>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

- Add Fiddle

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVr6g/) example

- UPDATE
  I just realised that you have $("...") so what i suggest you can  escape the single quote by putting  \

see updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vVr6g/1/)

Comment: i know this will work but i am generating the code on fly so how can i make my line of code work?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to do that in the [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) way

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("focus","#comment",function(){
    if($(this).val()=="Enter message here...")
       $(this).val("")   
    });        
});
```

Here is the sample http://jsfiddle.net/8UjkA/11/

Comment: Much better to use `if (this.value == this.defaultValue) this.value = '';` so that the default value can be set to anything suitable without changing the listener. It also means the reset button works as expected without additional code.